# GPG Decryption: Bad session key

Tags: linux, gnupg

I have encrypted a file with a passphrase using gpg on linux, however, when I tried to decrypt it on another machine with the exact passphrase, I am getting a bad session key error. Not sure how to resolve this, because I need to transfer a file securely on the mail. Could someone suggest me solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318041/gpg-decryption-failed-bad-session-key